# How do I implement a banner ad from MoPub in my Android Unity app?

Tags: unity, android, advertisements

I am new with Unity and everything and I have made a simple game. I wanted to put a MoPub banner ad on the game and I read [this](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/unity/banner/) on their site. But I was wondering where should I put that code from the site. Or even more useful if someone could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [introduction part of your link](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/unity/banner/#integration) seems straightforward. You can request the banner and display it whenever and wherever you want.

If you want to have a banner at the end of your level for example. Once you reach the end of the level you can just add the request / display code shown in the tutorial in the code that display the end of your game level, and the banner will be displayed. Once you are done (for example when player clicks on "play again"), you can simply hide, then destroy the banner.